# How do I expose an executable jar externally?

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, jhipster

I have a Jhipster monolithic (React/Java Springboot) application, compiled as an executable jar. I have dropped the jar in a folder on an Amazon EC2 instance. I believe the application builds correctly. I am provided an internal IP (or localhost) that I can access the site internally. However, I do not know how access this external to the server.

I am assuming that I should be using the EC2 instance public url with a port number. I.e. ec2-[specific container details omitted].compute-1.amazonaws.com with :80 or :8080 or :9000 or :443.

I have tried all of these ports. I have verified that these ports are exposed via my security policies. Every tutorial I have read stops before this step.

Comment: Do you have an internet gateway assigned to your VPC?  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html

Comment: Sorry, it took me a bit of time to research this answer. I do have the default IGW that was created by AWS. My EC2 instance is running on the same subnet as the default IGW. I think that that means that everything is in order as far as my IGW goes.

Additionally, I am able to SSH into the machine.